# How to databind more than 1 table to a listview

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

Right now this is my code, it only databinds the last mentioned table.

I have 2 tables the "Products" and "Phone", and I would like to databind both of them to the Listview1.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ListView1.DataSource = this.GetDatatable2();
        ListView1.DataSource = this.GetData();
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }

private DataSet GetData()
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CARP"].ConnectionString;
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Produtos WHERE Id= '" + Request.QueryString["Id"] + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
}

private DataSet GetDatatable2()
{
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CARP"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Phone WHERE Id= '" + Request.QueryString["Id"] + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Providing some example data would be helpful.

Comment: You can merge tables, but only if tables have same schema, if the y don't - you need introduce third table which combine data from both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it only binds the second table is, that you don't add the tables but set them as data source.

To add something you use the operator `+=` instead of `=`.

But in this situation this doesn't seem appropriate. I think you should merge both tables at first. With databinding the `ListView` would generate the columns automatically. Therefore you would need the same column headers in both tables. Anything else isn't meaningful at all.

You could use a SQL `UNION` and select both tables in one query, too.